# Apache http post example

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I am very new to this Apache http client. I have an URL to make a webservice call to one of the service. I was successfully executed with the GET request but I am trying to execute this with the POST request but I am not getting any response. I was unable to get the content from the entity.

My URL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?reference=CoQBcQAAAEZ7yCju-0lhU7sZIBBe_On9jYImWzZ9Zt5rIg1tX6zaH02dHrQMHF1LFHY1_yUuXzsUf6m6-rrQJ8Ec_mGxBYtV85Wyb4anakaUi3QuZj7ygJXB3Fd5x69k_4UnDKMmEBNa410vbCXgQOGIkHCbNpcbC8ENxmVlUrqiifmdfuLgEhCtPATMhFRdsjuyAL_j__OEGhTnqujRRMYy_5-kxzcqCdMY4_1dbA&sensor=true&key=key1";

This was executed with the GET method. Below u can see my code.

```
public class HttpClientPostExample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException {
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?";

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    // HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpsClientImpl.createRequest("Post", url);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairList
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                    "reference",
                    "CoQBcQAAAEZ7yCju-0lhU7sZIBBe_On9jYImWzZ9Zt5rIg1tX6zaH02dHrQMHF1LFHY1_yUuXzsUf6m6-rrQJ8Ec_mGxBYtV85Wyb4anakaUi3QuZj7ygJXB3Fd5x69k_4UnDKMmEBNa410vbCXgQOGIkHCbNpcbC8ENxmVlUrqiifmdfuLgEhCtPATMhFRdsjuyAL_j__OEGhTnqujRRMYy_5-kxzcqCdMY4_1dbA"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sensor", "true"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key",
            "AIzaSyBA0Hu3is9qIJ5v6NEuofigk0y-aQwqiP0"));
    httpPost.addHeader("User-Agent", "User-Agent");
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList, "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    Header[] headerArray = response.getAllHeaders();
    for (Header header : headerArray) {
        System.out.println("Header Name: " + header.getName()
                + " Header Value: " + header.getValue());
    }
}
```

Can any one help me on this. Is this the right approach to make a POST request...???

How can I get actual URL before firing/calling the execute method...???

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `client` instantiation technique from

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

to

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

and to make sure that your entity has been fully consumed, make a call to `EntityUtils.consume(entity)` before showing the reponse headers:

```
...
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
Header[] headerArray = response.getAllHeaders();
for (Header header : headerArray) {
    System.out.println("Header Name: " + header.getName()
            + " Header Value: " + header.getValue());
}
```